# Displaying records in view by id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a table that holds Questions and i also have a table that has the Questions ID listed in an answers table. For sake of duplicate data i only use the id.

My question is how do i populate "in the view" the question based on an ID from the current table. They are already joined by MainQuestionID. I am using DBEntities code first.

Here is my viewModel for the page.

```
    public class AuditFormEdit
    {
    public Models.MainQuestion MainQuestionID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MainQuestion> mainQuestion { get; set; }

    public List<SubcategoryHelper> SubcategoryHelperGet { get; set; }

    public class SubcategoryHelper : Models.SubCategory
    {
        public SubcategoryHelper(Models.SubCategory subCat)
        {
            this.SubCategoryID = subCat.SubCategoryID;
            this.SubcategoryName = subCat.SubcategoryName;
        }

    }


    public Models.MainAnswer MainAnswerInstance { get; set; }

    public List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper> ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList { get; set; }

    public void InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(List<Models.Score> ScoreList)
    {
        if (this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList == null)
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList = new List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper>();

        if (ScoreList != null
            && this.MainAnswerInstance != null)
        {
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Clear();
            ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper scoreCardCheckBoxHelper;
            string scoreTypes =
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MainAnswerInstance.Score) ?
                string.Empty : this.MainAnswerInstance.Score;
            foreach (Models.Score scoreType in ScoreList)
            {
                scoreCardCheckBoxHelper = new ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(scoreType);
                if (scoreTypes.Contains(scoreType.ScoreName))
                    scoreCardCheckBoxHelper.Checked = true;
                this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Add(scoreCardCheckBoxHelper);
            }
        }
    }


    public void PopulateCheckBoxsToScores()
    {
        this.MainAnswerInstance.Score = string.Empty;
        var scoreType = this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Where(x => x.Checked)
                              .Select<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper, string>(x => x.ScoreName)
                              .AsEnumerable();
        this.MainAnswerInstance.Score = string.Join(", ", scoreType);
    }


    public class ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper : Models.Score
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper() : base() { }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(Models.Score score)
        {
            this.ScoreID = score.ScoreID;
            this.ScoreName = score.ScoreName;
        }
    }



}
```

AS you can see i am calling out an ICollection for the MainQuestions but i am not sure how to populate the questions. They also have to populate based on a sectionID.

Revised 2:51 9-21-2012

Or how would i relate the two if i displayed the list of questions and then when answering it would update the answers table and not the current shown table.

Comment: Your choice of member names in your `AuditFormEdit` model make it ard to discern what you're trying to do.  e.g. Naming a `MainQuestion` `MainQuestionID` doesn't make much sense.  Perhaps just renaming your properties better will help make the solution more clear.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I should accept answers that do not answer the question?

Comment: Can you concisely explain what AuditFormEdit does?

Comment: AuditFormEdit updates MainAnswer where there is a column that is called score. It takes the records from a table called Scores and populates check boxes for the Score. When you select a score from the list and save it, it writes the name of the score in the column (comma separated) you can check more than one. I also have a menu in my layout that calls out the Questions from the Questions table. The only thing held in the Answers table is the MainQuestionID. So do i display the MainQuestions or Display MainAnswers and pull the Question by the ID and how? Maybe a Join?